# CSS/HTML: 2 Div's near each other with the second one's margin-left starting from the place the first div does

Tags: html, css

Right so I have two div's near each other.

The first div is just standing there with a width: 400px;
Then there's the other div using width: 400px; float:left and margin-left: 10%;; so that it goes near it.

The main problem is that when I resize the page it goes under it (which is what I want) but it starts the 10% from the second div so the second div isn't under the first div.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I would add `margin-right: 10%` to the first `div` instead. Then they will line up correctly.

Comment: Still does not solve my issue tho, because between the first div and the second one I need to have some sort of space so margin-left is required.

Comment: Whether Div1 has margin-right or Div2 has margin-left makes no difference: either way, there is a margin between them.

Answer (score 0):

Have fixed this, right so made the first DIV float to the right, the trick was to dump margin-right (sometimes margin gets bugged) and use padding-right: 10%;. I would like to thank Katstevens for his/her time.

Comment: Just be aware that using padding instead of a margin may cause other issues, especially if you are using the width and/or setting a background colour (there will be no perceived margin in the latter case). Glad to hear you solved it :)